# Не работают шрифты

Tags: html, css, scss

И так, вот мой файл fonts.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Dosis Book"; /* Имя шрифта */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-book-webfont.eot'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-book-webfont.ttf'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-book-webfont.woff'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-book-webfont.woff2'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-book-webfont.svg'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Dosis Semibold"; /* Имя шрифта */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-semibold-webfont.eot'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-semibold-webfont.ttf'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-semibold-webfont.woff'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-semibold-webfont.woff2'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url('../fonts/dosis-semibold-webfont.svg'); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
}
```

html :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
```

и scss:

```
$main-font-regular : 16px "Dosis Semibold";
font: $main-font-regular;
```

В чем может быть трабл?
В фаербаге шрифт горит серым, а не синим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что свой шрифт на сайте нужно подключать примерно так:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Leto_sans';
  src: url('fonts/leto_sans.eot');
  src: url('fonts/leto_sans.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/leto_sans.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('fonts/leto_sans.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/leto_sans.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/leto_sans.svg#Leto_sans') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Ну и хорошо проверяйте путь до шрифта, тут тоже часто бывают ошибки :)

Comment: На меня Пхпшторм ругается, если что. Не заработало, была проблема  в файле шрифта скорее всего. Скачал другой-сгененрил-заработало

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, если вы уверены, что ваш код работает, то может вы объясните для чего вы подключаете, не один файл, а 5? Потому что в вашем случае можно 1 файл подключить и ничего не изменится, другие всё равно не работают для тех целей, для которых они подключаются :)

Answer (score 0):

Такая проблема возникает, когда ваш шрифт не поддерживает кириллицу (если текст на сайте на русском языке), или же при генерации web-шрифта вы не выбрали его язык.